# Why is curl passing the string "@filename" rather than the contents of "filename"

Tags: curl, plsql

I am trying to use curl to pass a 1M xml file to be stored as a CLOB in a database table.  The command I am using is

`curl -X -d p_file=@myfile.xml https://hostname/pls/dad/package.myprocedure`

The procedure just takes the input and writes it to a CLOB in a database table.

```
procedure myprocedure(p_file IN clob)
is
begin
  insert into mytable (myclob) values (p_file);
end;
```

What I'm getting in my CLOB is "@myfile.xml"

If I use literal strings in place of the filename, like:

`curl -X -d p_file="This is my data"  https://hostname/pls/dad/package.myprocedure`

I get "This is my data" in the database table.

The server has curl v7.29.0 loaded on it.  Did the @ sign usage come along after that version?

Thanks!

Comment: `-d/--data[-ascii|-binary]` (unlike `-F/--form`) treats its argument as just `value`, so `@file` reads the file but `name=@file` doesn't. This allows it to be used for content-types which do not contain names, although the _default_ `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should. `--data-urlencode name@file` (no `=`) does read the file, URL-encode it, and send it as `name=encodedcontent`; that's probably what you want if your server is handling `x-www-form-urlencoded` per standards and your file is actual data not already encoded. Although 7.29 is pretty old, it does support (all of) these.

Comment: If I remove the "p_file=" from the command, I get an error message saying there's a missing "=" in the command string.

Comment: If I've got this straight, I should be using a command like like

``curl -X --data-urlencode p_file@myfile.xml etc., etc.``

I will give that a try tomorrow and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: I changed my command to 

``curl -X --data-urlencode p_file@myfile.xml url``

This time I got the message

Parameter value size 133864 exceeds limit of 32512 bytes

Does curl have a built-in file size limit that I need to change somewhere?

Comment: I didn't notice initially but `-X` requires a method name like `POST` or `PUT`, and using it alone should cause the command to fail outright. curl probably does have some limit on body size, but in my testing 10M works fine (far more than your size) plus curl error messages start with a 1- or 2-digit number in parentheses, so your error is probably from the server. Add `-v` to see headers sent and received, or `-i` to see just received.